# SQL SERVERでビュー中のサブクエリに外部から検索条件を設定したい

Tags: sql, sql-server

データの履歴管理をしたくてSQL SERVERで以下のようなビューを作成しようとしたのですが
サブクエリ内のカラムに対して外部から条件を設定する方がわかりません
条件式はサブクエリ内で与えないと正しい検索結果が出ないのでこの様にしたいです

ストアドにすると変数を設定できるのですが、この結果をさらに他の検索でJOINして使いたいので出来ればビューで作りたいのですが無理なのでしょうか

```
SELECT  COL1, COL2, DATE_FROM
FROM     MST_FOO INNER JOIN
   (SELECT    MAX(DATE_FROM) AS DATE_FROM
         FROM MST_FOO
         WHERE DATE_FROM <= '2020/1/1' -- ★ビューだと指定出来ない？
) AS DATE_MAX ON 
       MST_FOO.DATE_FROM = DATE_MAX.DATE_FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

ビューに条件を指定することはできません。

---

> ストアドにすると変数を設定できるのですが、この結果をさらに他の検索でJOINして使いたい

この用途でしたら、[ユーザー定義関数](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-ver15)のうちのテーブル値関数としてはどうでしょうか。[こちらのサンプル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#TVF)に

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.ufn_SalesByStore (602);
```

とあるように、テーブル値関数は`FROM`句に書けて、結果をテーブルとして扱えるので`JOIN`等も可能です。